# NSInvalidArgumentException [__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I'm building a XCTestCase that checks if a certain initializer work. I've already checked line by line of the code making sure I'm passing the right value for each key in the source dictionary (used in the class init). But I keep getting this error: NSInvalidArgumentException [__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]

Here's the test code:

```
NSDictionary *comments = @{@"data" : @{@"id": @"8675309",
                                @"text" : @"Sample Comment"}};

NSDictionary *user = @{@"id": @"8675309",
                      @"username" : @"d'oh",
                      @"full_name" : @"Homer Simpson",
                      @"profile_picture" : @"http://www.example.com/example.jpg"};

NSDictionary *sourceDictionary = @{@"id" : @"902810",
                                 @"user" : user,
                                 @"caption" : @{@"text" : @"a caption"},
                                 @"images" : @{@"standard_resolution" : @{@"url" : @"www.example.com.br/media"}},
                                 @"comments" : comments,
                                 @"likes" : @{@"count" : @"12342"},
                                 @"user_had_liked" : @"1"};

Media *testMedia = [[Media alloc] initWithDictionary:sourceDictionary];
```

And this is the class that I'm testing the initializer

```
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)mediaDictionary {

  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    self.mediaDictionary = mediaDictionary;

    self.idNumber = mediaDictionary[@"id"];

    self.user = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:mediaDictionary[@"user"]];

    [self tryToFetchCaption];

    [self tryToFetchImage];

    [self tryToFetchComments];

    [self setLikesCounter];

    BOOL userHasLiked = [mediaDictionary[@"user_had_liked"] boolValue];
    self.likeState = userHasLiked ? LikeStateLiked : LikeStateNotLiked;
  }

  return self;
}

-(void)setLikesCounter {

  NSInteger likeCount = [self.mediaDictionary[@"likes"][@"count"] intValue];
  self.likesCounter = @(likeCount);
}

-(void)tryToFetchCaption {

  NSDictionary *captionDictionary = self.mediaDictionary[@"caption"];

  if ([captionDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    self.caption = captionDictionary[@"text"];
  } else {
    self.caption = @"";
  }
}

-(void)tryToFetchImage {

  NSString *standardResolutionImageURLString = self.mediaDictionary[@"images"][@"standard_resolution"][@"url"];

  NSURL *standardResolutionImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:standardResolutionImageURLString];

  if (standardResolutionImageURL) {
    self.mediaURL = standardResolutionImageURL;
    self.downloadState = MediaDownloadStateNeedsImage;
  } else {
    self.downloadState = MediaDownloadStateNonRecoverableError;
  }
}

-(void)tryToFetchComments {

  NSMutableArray *commentsArray = [NSMutableArray new];

  for (NSDictionary *commentDictionary in self.mediaDictionary[@"comments"][@"data"]) {
    Comment *tempComment = [[Comment alloc] initWithDictionary:commentDictionary];
    [commentsArray addObject:tempComment];
  }

  self.comments = commentsArray;
}
```

Log:

```
2014-10-26 11:39:08.295 Blocstagram[2128:21707] -[__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc9d2074
MediaTests.m:47: error: -[MediaTests testThatInitializationWorks] : failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc9d2074"
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0119a946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00ad4a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x011a25c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x010eb3e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x010eafae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Blocstagram                         0x00060453 -[Comment initWithDictionary:] + 179
    6   Blocstagram                         0x00068ce4 -[Media tryToFetchComments] + 596
    7   Blocstagram                         0x00067db7 -[Media initWithDictionary:] + 519
    8   BlocstagramTests                    0x0c9cf74a -[MediaTests testThatInitializationWorks] + 1562
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0107d76d __invoking___ + 29
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0107d618 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 360
    11  XCTest                              0x2010897b -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 320
    12  XCTest                              0x20108bb9 -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 184
    13  XCTest                              0x20114162 -[XCTest run] + 314
    14  XCTest                              0x20107598 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 406
    15  XCTest                              0x20114162 -[XCTest run] + 314
    16  XCTest                              0x20107598 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 406
    17  XCTest                              0x20114162 -[XCTest run] + 314
    18  XCTest                              0x20107598 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 406
    19  XCTest                              0x20114162 -[XCTest run] + 314
    20  XCTest                              0x20103de2 __25-[XCTestDriver _runSuite]_block_invoke + 61
    21  XCTest                              0x20110c82 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 184
    22  XCTest                              0x20103d06 -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] + 285
    23  XCTest                              0x20104951 -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] + 272
    24  XCTest                              0x20104c6b -[XCTestDriver runTestSuite:completionHandler:] + 378
    25  XCTest                              0x2011775c +[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 216
    26  Foundation                          0x006d7b57 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 423
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x010f48d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x010f425d __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1309
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x010b36ba __CFRunLoopRun + 2090
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x010b2bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x010b29fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x058ff24f GSEventRunModal + 192
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x058ff08c GSEventRun + 104
    34  UIKit                               0x019f68b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    35  Blocstagram                         0x0008a32d main + 141
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x02deaac9 start + 1
)
Test Case '-[MediaTests testThatInitializationWorks]' failed (0.039 seconds).
Test Suite 'MediaTests' failed at 2014-10-26 13:39:08 +0000.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 0.039 (0.040) seconds
```

Comment: Which statement is causing the exception?

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: @Zaph When I try to init the testMedia.

Comment: @AaronBrager posted it

Comment: Which method in `testMedia` is causing the problem? As a last resort comment out the calls in the init method until the exception does not occur.

Comment: That approach worked really well for me. I commented out all the calls and went one by one. Found out that I was trying to pass a NSDictionary when I was supposed to pass a NSArray. As soon as I'm able to I will post the answer. Thanks @Zaph

Comment: @HotLicks that was exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which method in testMedia is causing the problem comment out the calls in the init method until the exception does not occur.